# Loop over a spark df and add new columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have some data like below:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("one two", "foo foo"),  
        ("one two", "bar bar"),
    ],
    ["label1", "label2"]  
)

df.show()
```

and I'm using `regex_replace()` to amend the string in the given column.

What I would like to do is loop over all columns in the df and apply the regex. I have some code below, but it is only saving the application of the regex to the last column. I think this is because the operation is not being appended to the dataframe:

```
names = df.schema.names
for name in names:
    new_df = df.withColumn(name, regexp_replace(name, " ", "_"))

display(new_df)
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

The data should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should be re-assigning the same dataframe in the loop, otherwise new_df will just have value of old dataframe + last modification.

```
names = df.schema.names
# Initialise new_df with existing df
new_df = df
for name in names:
    # Reassign value of new_df in each iteration
    new_df = new_df.withColumn(name, regexp_replace(name, " ", "_"))

display(new_df)
```

Input:

```
+-------+-------+
| label1| label2|
+-------+-------+
|one two|foo foo|
|one two|bar bar|
+-------+-------+
```

Output:

```
+-------+-------+
| label1| label2|
+-------+-------+
|one_two|foo_foo|
|one_two|bar_bar|
+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

**Also try this:**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace

df = spark.createDataFrame([("one two", "foo foo"), ("one two", "bar bar")], ["label1", "label2"])

for column in df.columns:
    # Assigning it to df again
    df = df.withColumn(column, regexp_replace(column, " ", "_"))

df.show()
```

**Output:**

```
+-------+-------+
| label1| label2|
+-------+-------+
|one_two|foo_foo|
|one_two|bar_bar|
+-------+-------+
```